# how can I generate a new column with values in dependence of a matrix/search logic?

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a column that has values in dependence of a matrix or solving logic like below.

Some Dummy-Data:

```
SomeDiscreteScale<-c("Black", "Black", "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", "Black")
AccordingValue<-c(1:7)
TemplateData<-data.frame(SomeDiscreteScale, AccordingValue)
```

A logic for assigning values:

```
a<-c("Black", "Red", "Green", "Blue")
b<-c(1:4)
SolvingLogic<-data.frame(a,b)
```

The final output should look like this:

```
solution<-c(1,1,2,3,4,4,1)
solution<-cbind(TemplateData, solution)
solution
```

The way I am doing it right now is to subset the Dummy data into the Discrete values (here it would be Black, Red, Green and Blue), add the desired new value and then bind the data again. This of course is horribly inconvenient. But how can I do this easier?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match`

```
 TemplateData$solution <- match(TemplateData$SomeDiscreteScale, SolvingLogic$a)
 TemplateData$solution
 #[1] 1 1 2 3 4 4 1
```

If the `SolvingLogic$b` have some other values, e.g.

```
 SolvingLogic$b <- letters[c(4,3,7,8)]
 TemplateData$solution <- SolvingLogic$b[match(TemplateData$SomeDiscreteScale,
                           SolvingLogic$a)]

 TemplateData$solution 
 #[1] "d" "d" "c" "g" "h" "h" "d"
```

Comment: This semed to work first, however what can I do if b is not b<--c(1:4), but b<-c(1,25,"Nice", "Not so nice")?

Comment: @user3021207  I did posted for that case too.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `match`, you can look at `merge` (but base R's `merge` can be slow at times and always seems to do funny things with the row orders):

```
merge(TemplateData, SolvingLogic, by.x = "SomeDiscreteScale", by.y = "a")
#   SomeDiscreteScale AccordingValue b
# 1             Black              1 1
# 2             Black              2 1
# 3             Black              7 1
# 4              Blue              5 4
# 5              Blue              6 4
# 6             Green              4 3
# 7               Red              3 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to `factor` with the levels argument set to `a` and then to `numeric`:

```
transform(TemplateData, solution = as.numeric(factor(SomeDiscreteScale, levels = a)))
#  SomeDiscreteScale AccordingValue solution
#1             Black              1        1
#2             Black              2        1
#3               Red              3        2
#4             Green              4        3
#5              Blue              5        4
#6              Blue              6        4
#7             Black              7        1
```

Just in case your actual "b" values in the lookup are more complex than 1:4, you could still use this approach with a tiny modification:

```
b <- letters[4:7]  # using some characters for the lookup
transform(TemplateData, solution = b[as.numeric(factor(SomeDiscreteScale, levels = a))])
#  SomeDiscreteScale AccordingValue solution
#1             Black              1        d
#2             Black              2        d
#3               Red              3        e
#4             Green              4        f
#5              Blue              5        g
#6              Blue              6        g
#7             Black              7        d
```